Inventory age estimation problem
Let's say I have a business that sells widgets.
Every day, the inventory of widgets changes as result of three types of events:

Deliveries of new widgets from suppliers (adds to total inventory)
Widgets sold and shipped from the factory (decreases total inventory)
Customer exchanges of one widget type for another (no effect on total inventory) (for simplicity, let’s say there are no outright returns)

When I first open the business, inventory tends to grow, but over time the daily inventory becomes stable, growing some days and shrinking other days.
Let's also say that I don’t have detailed records for these transactions but I want to estimate a distribution of the total inventory by age.  That is, I want to be able to say something like 20% of all widgets were received (through either deliveries or exchanges) in the last 5 days, 10% were received between 5 and 10 days ago, etc.
If I only have access to the daily inventory counts and the total volume of transactions per day, is there a reasonable way to estimate that distribution?
Note that, if the only transaction types were deliveries and shipments, it would be easy to determine the exact amount of each by solving for the proportion of total transactions to get the change in inventory for the day (it might be easier to solve this version of the problem first).  However, because exchanges are included in the total volume, the totals of deliveries and shipments can take on a range of values.  Also assume that I have no knowledge of the percentage of transactions that normally relate to exchanges.
An easy example to illustrate the concept would be if there were a day where total transactions were 1000 widgets and inventory increased by 1000 widgets.  I could then conclude that all transactions were deliveries.
As noted above, I only know the volume of transaction and daily ending balances.  Here’s what I don’t know:

The exact proportions of the three transaction types on a given day
The distributions of the proportions/volumes of the transaction types and any time series properties that they might have
Whether deliveries/sales can affect all widgets equally or whether certain widgets tend to remain in inventory for much longer.  It probably has to be assumed that all widgets could be shipped out with equal probability.

It might be that there are too many unknowns, but any thoughts on how to solve this or even just assumptions that need to be identified are appreciated.
Clarification: All transactions are made on a continuous basis.  That is, a widget could be delivered and then shipped out on the same day (or any combination of events that's possible in this example).

To model the age distribution of widgets in our inventory, we can employ a refined Markov chain approach. Let $X_t$ represent the age of a widget at time $t$, measured in days. We define the state space as $\{0, 1, 2, ..., s\}$, where state 0 represents a widget that has just been delivered or exchanged, other numeric states represent the age of the widget in days, and $s$ is an absorbing state representing sold widgets. The Markov chain transitions are governed by the following probabilities: $p_s$ is the probability of a widget being sold on any given day (transitioning to the absorbing state $s$), $p_e$ is the probability of a widget being exchanged (resetting to state 0), and $1 - p_s - p_e$ is the probability of a widget remaining in inventory and aging by one day. We can express the transition probabilities as:
$$P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i) = \begin{cases}
p_e & \text{if } j = 0 \text{ (exchanged)} \\
p_s & \text{if } j = s \text{ (sold, absorbing state)} \\
1 - p_s - p_e & \text{if } j = i + 1 \text{ (aging)} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
This Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution $\pi = (\pi_0, \pi_1, \pi_2, ...)$ for the non-absorbing states that satisfies $\pi_0 = p_e \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \pi_i$ and $\pi_k = (1 - p_s - p_e) \pi_{k-1}$ for $k \geq 1$. Solving this system of equations and normalizing to account for the outflow to the absorbing state, we find that the stationary distribution follows a geometric distribution:
$$\hat{\pi}_k = (p_s + p_e)(1 - p_s - p_e)^k \text{ for } k \geq 0$$
This distribution gives us the proportion of widgets in each age category among those still in inventory. The cumulative distribution function, representing the proportion of widgets that are $k$ days old or younger, is given by $P(X \leq k) = 1 - (1 - p_s - p_e)^{k+1}$. To estimate $p_s$ and $p_e$, we can use the observed data on daily inventory changes and transaction volumes. Let $\Delta I(t) = I(t) - I(t-1)$ be the daily change in inventory. Then, on average:
$$E[\Delta I(t)] = E[d(t)] - E[s(t)] = (1 - p_s)V(t) - p_s I(t-1)$$
$$E[V(t)] = E[d(t)] + E[s(t)] + E[e(t)] = V(t) + p_e I(t-1)$$
From these equations, we can estimate $p_s$ and $p_e$ using methods such as least squares or maximum likelihood estimation. Once we have these estimates, we can calculate the expected age distribution of widgets in our inventory.

This is a very thoughtful answer and I appreciate it.  I'm familiar with Markov models although not as the much the math, but that explanation does make sense.  For the last part, should the first term in the change in inventory equation be $(1 - p_s - p_e)V(t)$?  I'm also not sure I'm following the last equation.  Wouldn't $E[V(t)] = V(t)$ since we know $V(t)$?  I would think $p_eI(t - 1)$ should be included in $V(t)$.

Also, I've updated the question to clarify this, but all activity is happening on a continuous basis even though I only have data on a daily basis.  That is, a widget could be delivered and then shipped back out in the same day (or any combination of events that's possible in this scenario).  I'm guessing the continuous solution is more complicated but I think a discrete solution should be close enough where volume is small compared to inventory.
